# JavaFX editable combo box

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to use a editable combo box. In that I want to add a listener for pressing ENTER key. I tried the below options but none of them working.:(

`cmb_year` is the combo box object.

```
cmb_year.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            }else
            {


            }
        }
    });




cmb_year.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            }else
            {


            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
cmb_year.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("Entered");
            }else
            {


            }
        }
    });
```